# Could someone please help why this line of code is giving me an Object defined error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

`activeCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=SUM(" & activeCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & "+" & activeCell.Offset(0, -4).Address & "+" & activeCell.Offset(0, -6).Address & "+" & activeCell.Offset(0, -8).Address & "+" & activeCell.Offset(0, -10).Address & ")"`

Comment: 1. you don't use `+` in [`SUM`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) function of Excel, either use list separator (`,` or `;`) or don't use `SUM`. 2. What is your activeCell? Maybe `OFFSET` drives it out from the worksheet?

Comment: Remove SUM, use single addition.

Comment: @MátéJuhász *What is your activeCell?* It doesn't matter in that case - some ActiveCell exists (if not the error message must differ), and all term expressions references to it (the formula is worksheet-localized). *Maybe OFFSET drives it out from the worksheet?* It can be detected on a calculation stage, not while entering formula.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes. While assigning formula to a cell using VBA code the 'out of worksheet' condition is not checked, so it cannot be a source of error in question. It must be "Application-defined or Object-defined Error" because of error in Offset method.

Comment: If you want to use SUM then,, `Activecell.Formula = "=SUM(G13,I13,K13)"`

Comment: **,, Cont,,** or your formula should like this,, `Activecell.Formula= ActiveCell.Offset(, 4).Value+ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value+ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value`

Comment: @MátéJuhász, it will not matter if you use "+" or "," and I am working in only one worksheet.

Comment: I stored the expression result in a string variable and this is what it has stored. "=SUM($M$11+$K$11+$I$11+$G$11+$E$11)"

And I tried putting this direct formula in a cell, it works fine.

Comment: @Akshay, why don't  you also try what I've suggested for Offset command in my 2nd comments it's working properly! ☺

Comment: @RajeshS, I want to leave formula there, so I cant just add the values and set it. For future purpose.

Comment: I have found the solution guys, VBA will not let you pass the values which has "$" in it. And I was using absolute values. When I set RowAbsolute and ColumnAbsolute as False, it worked smoothly. 

Thank you so much guys :) @MátéJuhász, RajeshS, Akina

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
activeCell.Offset(0, -2).Address
```

use this,

```
activeCell.Offset(0, -2).Address(RowAbsolute:= False, ColumnAbsolute:= False)
```

Comment: But  this will only return the cell address ,, what abut the SUM as your OP ?

Comment: Formula for sum will not change, that will remain the same.
So at the end it will look like-
activeCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & activeCell.Offset(0, -2).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & "," _
                                                & activeCell.Offset(0, -4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & "," _
                                                & activeCell.Offset(0, -6).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)& ")"